# How to set a few emails in a method setReplyTo from MimeMessage class?

Tags: java, email, gmail

I want to set a few emails in a method `setReplyTo` from `MimeMessage` class.
This method has an argument `Address[] addresses`, so I call it:

```
    email.setReplyTo(new Address[] { new InternetAddress("firstmail@gmail.com"), new InternetAddress("secondmail@gmail.com") });
```

Of course email is an object of `MimeMessage` class.

Unfortunately it's not correct code and I can't send my mail.
If I want to set only one email, everything is OK and I can do this on many ways.

I read many similar topics, but nowhere find an example of set a few emails in `setReplyTo(Address[] addresses)` method.

Comment: Why not? What happens?

Comment: Could you please share the error you get when you execute your code?

Comment: I don't have the error in my console.
I get an email with information that an error occurred and the message was not sent. Moreover senders of this mail are: me (what's obvious) and Bounce <nobody@gmail.com>.